# convert words from english to russian in android

Tags: android

i want to convert words from english to russian .so let me know how it possible in offline mode I would be grateful if someone can help me. Is there a way to use english to russia translation
any help is appriciable

thanks in advance..

Comment: I guess you can use the google translate api https://developers.google.com/translate/

Comment: Perhaps this service appears to be free. Yandex :- http://api.yandex.com/translate/

Comment: Please note that if you do this you'll probably get an unreadable mess.  Automatic translation is still horrible, and the smaller the number of words the worse it is (since context improves results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way i see for you doing this would be to have a local database that you would have filled with a "dictionnary" ... you can not contact any API if you are offine so fill it and make request on it when you need to transate a word ;)

regards.

Comment: is it possible in online mode?

Comment: of course it is ;) you can contact any API if you are online. Do not hesitate to accept my answer by clicking the check on the left of my post if it was helpful to you :) regards.